# Am I understanding correctly the Maximum Entropy concept using a sentence?

Tags: maximum-entropy, example

In the sentence "*The house is white*", each word carries a different amount of information. If I remove the "*The*" from the sentence, almost nothing happens: you are still able to visualize a white house. If I remove the "*is*", the uncertainty increases, since it could be that the house "*was*", "*is*" or "*will be*", and thus increases the entropy. When I remove the word "*white*", the entropy is even bigger, since the sentence "*The house is*" could end with information about colour, size, location, and a long etc. That is, there is an increase in the entropy. Finally, if I remove "*house*" you cannot guess what I'm talking about: a cloud? a bird?, a car? that is the entropy would reach, in this case, it's maximum... Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. If entropy is the inverse of information (or maybe a more esoteric meaning like the entropy of the distribution of all possible meanings of the sentence), the word whose suppression makes the bigger entropy increase is indeed house.